# Removing date from string in PHP

Tags: php, date, preg-replace

I am trying to remove all dates from strings in PHP using preg_replace(). The dates are of the following formats: YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY.MM.DD

```
$string1 = "Current from 2014-10-10 to 2015-05-23";    
$output = preg_replace('/\d{4}[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/g', '', $string1);
```

Expected output is "Current from  to ". Currently I am getting back "".

Any help greatly appreciated! Wonko

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Should be getting `Unknown modifier 'g'`

Comment: Good catch, I found this in the logs:  PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
$input = "Current from 2014-10-10 to 2015/05/23 and 2001.02.10";
$output = preg_replace('/(\d{4}[\.\/\-][01]\d[\.\/\-][0-3]\d)/', '', $input);
echo $output;
```

**Update**
To ensure that the date also is valid

```
<?php
$input = "Current from 2014-10-10 to 2015/05/23 and 2001.19.10";
$output = preg_replace_callback('/(\d{4}[\.\/\-][01]\d[\.\/\-][0-3]\d)/', function($matches) {
    $date = str_replace(array('.','/'), '-', $matches[1]);
    $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    if($newDate->format('Y-m-d') == $date) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}, $input);
echo $output;
```

Comment: I think it's because OP didn't make an a match in the regex. And yes adding month 19 and day 39 will be a false positive. That could easly be fixed by using `preg_replace_callback` to check if the date is valid, but i thougt it was not needed in this case.

Comment: I do need to be careful not to remove invalid dates, or at least as best as possible!

Comment: Thanks Karl, that solution is working perfectly! Rock on man!